# Retrieval of alphabetical interval with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

As far as I know, boto3 returns objects sorted alphabetically by their key. Is there any way to retrieve an interval from this alphabetical order without retrieval of all objects, and then do pagination over the result?

Example: Let's say I have the following objects in the storage:

```
aa/example+0+0013399841.json
ba/example+0+0013400780.json
ba/example+0+0013403134.json
cj/example+0+0013416534.json
df/example+0+0013419528.json
ef/example+0+0013420605.json
```

I would like to have something like `get_interval(FirstPrefix='a', LastPrefix='d')`, which would get me objects (or more preferably paginator) corresponding to these keys:

```
ba/example+0+0013400780.json
ba/example+0+0013403134.json
cj/example+0+0013416534.json
df/example+0+0013419528.json
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) command has a `StartAfter` parameter:

> **StartAfter** (string) -- StartAfter is where you want Amazon S3 to start listing from. Amazon S3 starts listing after this specified key. StartAfter can be any key in the bucket.

However, there is on way to say "Stop at this prefix".

Please note that the `Prefix` field is normally used for specifying folders/sub-directories in conjunction with a `Delimiter`.